# Show url with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a script, after finishing something, a button with an link will appear, before the button is not clickable. but i have a problem.

this is the code:

```js
FB.ui(e, function(t) {
        if (t["post_id"]) {
          //your download content goes here
          // Do something there
    var secret_data = "<a href=\"http://TEST.com\">";
          jQuery("#results").html(secret_data);
        } 
    })
```

```html
<div id="results"><img src="img/button.png"></a>
```

I thought that after finishing this action that the code would look like this:

```
<a href="http://TEST.com"><img src="img/button.png"></a>
```

But it isn't..

So does someone have the answer ?

Comment: Possibly because you are replacing all of the html inside the div with only one tag? Try using `.append()` or `.before()` and `.after()`

Comment: Sorry, but can you tell me how this will look ?

Comment: Yeah, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Can u enclose properly `div` and `a` tags in output as well as in input `<div id="results"><img src="img/button.png"></a>`

Comment: This is not clear at all what html already exists or what exactly your objective is

Comment: Is your output should be `<div id="results"><a href="http://TEST.com"><img src="img/button.png"></a> </div>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to wrap an `<a>` around an existing image use [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
$('#results img').wrap('<a href="http://TEST.com"></a>');
```

Using `html()` replaces everything in the target element with the new content

Comment: Sry but i don't understand this. i replaced this  $('#results img').wrap('<a href="http://TEST.com"></a>'); now with this <a href=\"http://TEST.com\"> is this right ?

Comment: Why did you remove closing tag?

Comment: No my code is looking now like this `var secret_data = "$('#results img').wrap('<a href=\"http://lnkgo.com/3BIu\"></a>'); ";
          jQuery("#results").html(secret_data);
` but i made something wrong, sorry i don't know how to add this.

Comment: As mentioned in answer `html()` replaces everything. You are wrapping the image then replacing everything right after that

Comment: remove the line `jQuery("#results").html(secret_data);`

Comment: Ok but the result is the same right ? `<div id="results"><img src="img/weiter.png"></a>` because nothing happens

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Your html for button should be a div with button image(not clickable) like

```
<div id="results"><img src="img/button.png"></a>
```

And Javascript code to add the active button should be like

```
var secret_data = '<a href="http://TEST.com"><img src="img/button.png"></a>';
jQuery("#results").html(secret_data);
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Yes thank you, but i want the button to be there before, just don't clickable.

Comment: Updated the code, div will have button image by default just not the <a> tag